# How to add parenthesis to the caputures of the regex pattern in php?

Tags: php, regex

I want to add parenthesis to the variable inside string. how can I do it on php using regex?

String:
`UPDATE item_tbl SET name = '$name',code = '$code',category_fk = $category_fk,modified_by_fk = $modified_by_fk,price = $price`

regex pattern:
`/\$(\w*)/g`

Output :

`UPDATE item_tbl SET name = '($name)',code = '($code)',category_fk = ($category_fk),modified_by_fk = ($modified_by_fk),price = ($price)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
(\$\w+)
```

and replace by this:

```
($1)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hfvGUe/2/)

Sample Solution ( [run here](https://ideone.com/I9qzv8) )

```
$re = '/(\$\w+)/';
$str = 'UPDATE item_tbl SET name = \'$name\',code = \'$code\',category_fk = $category_fk,modified_by_fk = $modified_by_fk,price = $price';
$subst = '($1)';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Sample Output:

```
UPDATE item_tbl SET name = '($name)',code = '($code)',category_fk = ($category_fk),modified_by_fk = ($modified_by_fk),price = ($price)
```